# Change caret icon each time while loop goes through

Tags: php

I have this `while` loop that dynamically displays a navigation menu name depending on what value is in the database. But I would like to change the caret or `glyficons` for each new menu. Any ideas?

```
 <?php while($parent =mysqli_fetch_assoc($pquery)) : ?> <!-- loops
  through
 database to find parent name = 0  -->
  <?php
   $parent_id = $parent['id']; /* stored parent id within parent_id */
   $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent ='$parent_id'";
   $cquery = $db->query($sql2);
  ?>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo 
  $parent['category']; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-
  down"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cquery)) : ?>
      <li><a href="category.php?cat=<?=$child['id'];?>"><?php echo 
    $child['category']; ?></a></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
  </li>
  &nbsp;
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague, so lets get some specifics. 1. What do you want to change each menu icon with? Are you able to alter your database table? What have you tried so far? Give an example of what you are rendering and also what you want to render.

Comment: i currently have glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down icon displayed next to each menu title, but i would like to use different glyphicons or icons for each menu. i.e components (with a components icon) storage (with a storage icon) etc. Because of the while loop i have, it only allows me (or so my knowledge says) to use glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down icon.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my wild guess is you talk about the following icons http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp

In your script they are defined by

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo 
  $parent['category']; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-
  down"></span></a>
```

If you know your category names you can just create an array that has definitions for an icon for each category like:

```
$icons = array("Category 1" => "lock", "Category 2" => "repeat");
```

Then just call these in your script by:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo 
  $parent['category']; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<?php echo $icons[$parent['category']]; ?>"></span></a>
```

However, if you dont know your category names, you have to count the rows from your parent query (`mysqli_fetch_assoc($pquery)`) with `mysqli_num_rows` and count up while you are going through the results. With an array using integers as keys

```
$icons = array(0 => "lock", 1 => "repeat")
```

you can access a new icon for each entry.
Hope I could help.

Comment: thanks, just so i get this right, the Category 1 in your example would be the $parent['category'] (the 'category') which corrosponds to the category name within my database.

Comment: An example then would be .
$icons = array("Components (Category 1)" => "lock", "Storage (Category 2)" => "repeat");

am i right?

what would i put instead of "lock" and "repeat"?

Comment: If your database has a category named "Cool News Category", your array looks like $icons=array("Cool News Category"=>"lock"); The possible icons are listed here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp